# Android NDK: clang toolchain with Android Studio 2.2, gradle, and externalNativeBuild + Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to set up an NDK project using the new externalNativeBuild with an Android.mk, but I'm getting different results when I compile on the command line versus through Android Studio.  I'm trying to confirm which toolchain Android Studio is using, but cannot figure out how to specify it given the new syntax.

So far, I have added `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` to my Application.mk

If I rename app/src/main/cpp -> app/src/main/jni and run ndk-build on the command line, my static libs and shared lib are compiled as expected.

However, with `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` specified there, my project view in Android Studio shows an object file for every source file in the static libraries.

I am currently on Windows 10 using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6.

Should I be specifying this elsewhere?

Comment: may you try one of samples here to see if you get the similar thing: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild  ?  also after you build on command line, before re-build with android studio, run rmdir  /S /Q your-proj/app/.externalNativeBuild to remove any cached values there.  If your application.mk and android.mk are in the same directory, they will be used by default

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be specified in `build.gradle` as flags in `Application.mk` are apparently being ignored (at least at this moment).

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "-DNDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: flags in Application.mk is used as long as it is in the same dir as Android.mk; otherwise need to specify the path to your Application.mk on arguments line in module build.gradle